# Text is missing When i use ellipsis inContent editable Div in Google chrome

Tags: html, css

I am working on `text-overflow: ellispsis` property in google chrome. When i add more text to the div which is Content Editable, the whole text is missing.

Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/dineshk/ukwf8od7/

**I am using google chrome 35 +**

HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="edit">This is a Test case,Its a testing text not actual text</div>
```

CSS

```
.edit {
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
    background:#dcdcdc;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

Comment: @Mr. Alien Can you look into this issue.

Comment: checked in chrome 36. the text still shows when new content added.

Comment: @KheemaPandey: In Chrome v24 and I can see the problem. Maybe something to do with older browsers possibly. The issue can be seen when you click on the div and use the right arrow to traverse to the end of the content.

Comment: @Kheema Pandey try adding more than 20 text...plz

Comment: @Harry aah I see while testing I also encounter this problem..

Comment: its look like chrome have unexpected behavior when using ` contenteditable="true"` feature with `text-overflow:ellipsis;`. The text actually won't show but its contain spacing..

Comment: @Mr. Alien plz help me

Comment: @Kheema Pandey yeah,,that how to resolve ? any idea

Comment: Its clear that Chrome doesn't properly work well and I can say it is really a chrome bug.. lets see other senior Member might have some words

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this is pretty old, but I ran into this issue and none of the answers here gave me what I wanted. The issue is occurring because when a contentEditable div becomes unfocused, it remains scrolled to whatever character position you were editing at, and if those characters were outside what can fit in the text box, they will now be hidden.

To get around this, you can scroll the div back to the left on blur.

```
function scrollBack (el) {
   el.scrollLeft = 0;
}
```

See JsFiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/sawsym/5kaec481/3/

Comment: This is Amazing

Comment: how much headache this gave me... I was looking through endless topics like, go back with cursor to the beginning etc, and yet this works... lol

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ukwf8od7/2/)**

just a this `text-overflow: clip;` to div on focus

css

```
.edit {
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
    background:#dcdcdc;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap
}
.edit:focus {
    text-overflow: clip;
}
```

I guess this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ukwf8od7/3/)** should solve the problem, on unfocus taking the text-overflow back to ellipsis.

```
.edit:focus {
    text-overflow: clip;
}
.edit:not(:focus) {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: +1. Very nice answer. Not sure if user is OK with the ellipsis going away on focus. That is the one drawback of this approach but I guess there is no alternate option.

Comment: Thanks, but it not work. You try add more text, isay more than 20,30 text, whole text will disappear

Comment: I found a problem with this is text only shows when you focus on input.

Comment: @Deekey: Correct, when the cursor is at the end and you tab or focus out it is back to invisible. But when you do home and tab out (I know thats not much help) it is visible.

Comment: unfocus taking the text-overflow back to ellipsis not solvign it  4dgaurav

Answer (score 1):

I know that this discussion is old now but in my case, following @Swiss's answer, I had to do the `scrollLeft = 0` assignment on `el.target` as:

```js
    function scrollToStart (el) {
        el.target.scrollLeft = 0
    }
```

I would like to add here that I was working on VueJS 2.x and had created a `contenteditable` `div`. I added the above call in the `blur` event's handler and it worked as desired!

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine with these code

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dineshk/ukwf8od7/4/.)**

`direction:rtl` is working fine in google chrome. So i used `rtl`

**HTML**

```
<div class="edit" contenteditable="true">This is a Test case,Its a testing text not actual text hello i am dinesh from Calicut Kerala, its india, i am working in Ricoh Innovation pvt limited in bangalore. I am working as a ui Developerddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
```

**Jquery**
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.edit').click(function(){
        $('.edit').addClass("ellipsisfocus")
        })

```
    $('.edit').blur(function(){
    $('.edit').removeClass("ellipsisfocus")
    $('.edit').addClass("ellipsisClass")

    })
    $(":not(.edit)").click(function(){
    //alert('hi')
    $('.edit').removeClass("ellipsisClass")
    $('.edit').addClass("edit")
    })

    })
```

**CSS**

```
.ellipsisfocus{text-overflow:clip !important;}
.edit{width:150px; height:20px; background:#dcdcdc; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;}
.ellipsisClass{width:151px !important; height:21px; background:#c0c0c0; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;direction:rtl;}
```

Comment: @Kheema Pandey  check i have found a solution

Comment: @ Harry i hope this answer will help you. Later i found